# After installing ubuntu.....windows is not opening

Tags: boot

I installed ubuntu 15.10 alongside windows 8.1 .BUt after the installation ubuntu works,but windows does not work.How to fix it?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

For more information, refer this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)